# Can I install a window behind a window?

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

Can I install a window behind a window?

This is useful for soundproofing. Window inserts do this, but an inswing casement window is better.

I have a double hung double pane window.

frame dimensions:
It's 53x33 inches. What would the minimum depth from the indoors edge of the frame to the old window be? Mine is > 3.75 inches. It's possible I might make the wall and frame thicker.

Some things that improve soundproofing:

1. A better seal
2. High surface density (mass per unit area)
3. Have 2 panes with a big open distance between them.

Example: A window has 2 panes 4 inches apart. Adding a third pane in the middle could reduce soundproofing because the biggest open distance between panes is ~2 inches instead of 4. It's called the triple leaf effect.

4. Reduce the coincidence effect. This is worst when the surface density of all panes is the same.
5. Constrained layer damping from laminated glass.

Comment: This sounds like you want to take a trip from Miami to Seattle and your planned route goes through  San Diego.   WHY?  Is your goal making simple things complicated?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: It seems like you know the technicals, so why ask us.  Anything you do is better than nothing. For best results, replace the joinery with double glazing or triple glazing, with an appropriate gas in between.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Beware of making required egress windows non-functional for egress or rescue.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I install a window behind a window?

You can install anything behind anything.  Or anything anywhere that you want.

[image]

It will be more or less challenging and will or will not do what you want it to do depending on the specific of your circumstances (of which we know little to none).

> What would the minimum depth from the indoors edge of the frame to the old window be? Mine is > 3.75 inches.

You can always build up the frame into the opening or out from the inside face of the wall to make more room if you you really want.  Windows might have a flange on the outside in which case you need a flat surface on the outside like the face of the outside wall to place that against.  Or you cut off the flange.  If it's a flangeless insert, it would be easier but we don't know how your window casing is, if you're willing to tare that out, etc.

Also you can list all the reasons for why more panes is better for soundproofing that you want but at some point the sound coming through your wall is going to become noticeable depending on what kind of wall it is.  If it's solid concrete, maybe it won't.  I'm not bothering doing further sound-insulation on my windows because I can hear traffic through the actual walls.

Creative solutions like this may also not pass code and, even if they do, will make a house more difficult to sell in the future.